# ASP.Net WebAPI Returning Empty Objects In List

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I am making a GET request to a WebAPI and returning an object like so:
http://s12.postimg.org/leoykz3rh/debug1.png

However, when I am retrieving the object on the client side, the objects in *Elements* are empty with no structure:
http://s12.postimg.org/cie6h1d59/debug2.jpg

Here is the class definition of the objects contained in *Elements*

```
public class LineElement
    {
        int ID { get; set; }
        int X { get; set; }
        int Y { get; set; }
        int W { get; set; }
        int H { get; set; }
        string Code { get; set; }
        string Color { get; set; }

        public LineElement(int pID, int? pX, int? pY, int? pW, int? pH, string pCode, string pColor)
        {
            ID = pID;
            X = Convert.ToInt16(pX);
            Y = Convert.ToInt16(pY);
            W = Convert.ToInt16(pW);
            H = Convert.ToInt16(pH);
            Code = pCode;
            Color = pColor;
        }
    }
```

They are added to *Elements* like so:

```
var elemList = new List<LineElement>(); // list of LineElements to return
for (var i = 0; i < r.Count(); i++)
                {
                    elemList.Add(new LineElement(r[i].ID, r[i].P_L, r[i].P_T, r[i].P_W, r[i].P_H, r[i].Code.ToString(), r[i].GetSColor()));
                }
```

And as you can see from the VS debugger screenshot, the object looks fine on the server-side. Any thoughts on what may be happening during serialization or de-serialization?

Also, I have tested the serialization by passing it back to the client using  IHttpActionResult which gives me the same result.

```
return Ok(response);
```

Thanks

Comment: Is anyone of my suggestion worked for you?

Comment: Yes - I can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following,

a. Make properties public.

```
  public int ID { get; set; }
```

b. Return the value as shown below,

```
 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, lineElementList);
```

c. Make sure you have HttpGet attribute in the method.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Methodname()
    {
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this error because I was missing  { get; set; } in the properties.

Changed:

public int ID;

To:

public int ID { get; set; }

Comment: We were migrating projs from .NETCore 2_1 to .NET 6, this indeed saved a lot of time, still wondering how it worked without the setters and getters earlier.